# Ordinary Differential Equation and graphs theory?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graph-theory

Is there any application of Ordinary Differential Equation in graphs theory?

Comment: Or viceversa ... ?

Comment: Network flow problems can often be cast as coupled systems of ODEs. The most familiar examples of course come from electrical circuit theory and Kirchhoff's circuit laws.

Comment: Yeah! Or viceversa!

Comment: I understood! Thanks!